# iOS Today Extension - Share core data between

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, ios8, today-extension

I have an app which uses core data and i'm trying to add a today extension to it which also access the data
I have it set up so far and its able to access the data, but i'm having trouble with the classes for the entities.
I get the following error

> CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'Med_Track_2.Medicine' for entity 'Medicine'

`Med_Track_2` is the product name for the main app, `Medicine_Tracker_2` is the name for the extension
The medicine class is added to both targets

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to share the resources between your app and your extension. Read the "Sharing Data with Your Containing App" chapter: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1

Also you have to add the files you want to use to the Extension's target too.
(Edit the Build phases / Compile Sources sections of the extension's target)

Comment: ok, so that says to use a framework, but even with a framework i get the unable to load class error

Comment: Did you edit the Extensions Target to link with that framework?

Comment: yeah, both the extension and the main app are linked, main app works but the extension doesn't

Comment: changing the class name to the extensions project makes the extension work (though no data is showing) but the main app then errors

Comment: and when using it from the extension no data is being shown and the fetchedresultscontroller has no returned objects

Comment: Did you build the framework to arm64 too? Did you set the app groups as explained in the link above?

Comment: I think you have to read the whole App Extension guide before you continue, to understand the whole concept, maybe watch the latest WWDC videos about the extensions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61507/discussion-between-ceri-turner-and-kaszas-david).

Comment: ok, i've got past that error but i'm getting an error when trying to create an object
 
the code is
let instance = Singleton.sharedInstance
NSLog("MOC: %@", instance.moc)
var med : Medicine = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Medicine", inManagedObjectContext: instance.moc) as Medicine
 
but its crashing with exc_breakpoint exc_arm_breakpoint
 
console output is
2014-09-18 16:38:55.974 Med Track 2[8103:140340] MOC: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x16d78240>
 
so i know the managed object context is ok